# Does online compiling optimize readonly variables on nodeMcu ram?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I've done several searches but wasn't able to find some documentation about the online compiler that comes with nodeMcu. I am writing some basic code, but with a lot of "const variables", that is like a #define in C. This variables are read only, and I use just for documentation and quickly change of program at development time.
As I know that RAM is tinny at nodeMcu (esp12 modules), I need to know if compiling files by calling node.compile() does help me with RAM saving by optimize this constants and placing it into some ROM memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does help. The full answer, however, is reading the dedicated chapter in our FAQ at http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/lua-developer-faq/#techniques-for-reducing-ram-and-spiffs-footprint (way to long to quote here).